# SQL - Is there a way know if a record exit in a source when joining 2 sources

Tags: sql, join, left-join

SQL - Is there a way know if a record exist in a source when joining 2 sources.

I am joining 2 sources S1 and S2 on a common field A. Lets S1 is a master list and contains all the records, whereas S2 is subset of S1 for A values.

```
SELECT S1.A, S1.B, S2.C
FROM S1 (NOLOCK) LEFT JOIN
     S2 (NOLOCK)
     ON S1.A = S2.A;
```

Is there a way to add a custom field in the SELECT to determine if that A record is present in S2 or not?

Comment: Using a left join as you are, S2.A will be Null if the rows doesn't exist...

Comment: Why isn't the `NULL` value for the third column sufficient?

Answer (score 4):

this should work:

```
SELECT S1.A, S1.B, S2.C,
       test=(case when s2.a is null then 'present' else 'not present' end) 
FROM S1 (NOLOCK) LEFT JOIN
     S2 (NOLOCK)
     ON S1.A = S2.A;
```